# How to optimize CPU load up to 100% with GZip multithread archiver?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, gzip

I've been working on a multithreaded file archiver for a week now, it works exclusively on clean threads. Synchronization is achieved by monitors and AutoResetEvent.
I allocated the number of threads to the number of cores like that:

```
public static int GetCoreCount()
        {
            int coreCount = 0;
            foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get())
            {
                coreCount += int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString());
            }
            return coreCount;
        }
```

But that load my CPU max ~65%.
And this load is far from uniform, it constantly falls and rises.
Tell me. Does anyone have any idea how to use 100% processor capability?
This is my Run() code :

```
 public void Run()
        {
            var readingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadInFile));
            var compressingThreads = new List<Thread>();
            for (var i = 0; i < CoreManager.GetCoreCount(); i++)
            {
                var j = i;
                ProcessEvents[j] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                compressingThreads.Add(new Thread(() => Process(j)));
            }
            var writingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteOutFile));

            readingThread.Start();

            foreach (var compressThread in compressingThreads)
            {
                compressThread.Start();
            }

            writingThread.Start();

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(ProcessEvents);
            OutputDictionary.SetCompleted();

            writingThread.Join();
```

Comment: Are you sure your file system isn't the bottleneck? You could have all the threads you want, but if you're reading files from a slow disk/over a network connection there's a real limit there.

Comment: time to use a profiler, don't try such activity with random tries.

Comment: @WaiHaLee yep. You are right. I understand that but if we talk about WinRar or 7Zip. They use maximum system resources or I don't understand anything about that? :D

Comment: @OznOg but what exactly i should check? Proccesor load? I use that  but the results +- are the same

Comment: process load is not profiling: use a tool that tells you where the cpu is taken in your code, and where parallelization is effective

Comment: Wow. That is a nice idea, that tool available in Visual Studio? And what I should to do? ;D

Comment: @WaiHaLee you are right.

Comment: High CPU usage doesn't necessarily equate to efficiency. I'm not saying this is the case but a program could easily use 100% of the CPU resources but still take *longer*. For instance you could add some more threads to your application to do unrelated, resource-hungry tasks - it'd be at 100% load but might take longer. This is the sort of thing that, as had been said, you'd use a profiler for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to tell what is limiting your core usage without profiling, and also knowing how much data you are compressing in your test.

However I can say that in order to get good efficiency, which includes both full core utilization and close to a factor of *n* speedup for *n* threads over one thread, in [pigz](https://github.com/madler/pigz) I have to create pools of threads that are always there, either running or waiting for more work. It is a huge impact to create and destroy threads for every chunk of data to be processed. I also have pools of pre-allocated blocks of memory for the same reason.

The source code at the link, in C, may be of help.

Comment: Yep, I saw that lib. Unfurtanaly I can't use ThreadPool but maybe I should create custom ThreadPool :D thank you )